# Intel Computer Stick Black screen after restore clonezilla image

Tags: gnome, login-screen, openbox

I'm having some problems with a project I'm working with Intel Computer Stick.
When I clone the finished project and restore the image to another computer stick with the same spec I can't log to the gnome desktop, all i get is a black screen for like 3 seconds then it take me back to the OS login screen.
I have installed Openbox for this project i can access the terminal. I have executed commands to restart gdm, to start lightdm, i even executed unity --reset and nothing seems to work. Another thing for some reason my wireless device doesn't work on Openbox but if i logout it works at the login screen but i can't join any network cause of permission problems.
Does anybody care to give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i found the problem to be generated by GPT and UEFI partitions. I solved the problem creating & restoring an image using dd command.